# After rotating an image, how do i save it with the same quality as before rotating?

Tags: android, jpeg, image-uploading, android-bitmap, image-compression

I need to send a picture from my app to the server. However before I send it I need to do some little modifications on it like rotating it. My problem is to know what quality to save it before sending it to the server. I tried

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileoutputstream);
```

file size before: **1.5mb** - file size after **3 mb** :(
so it seems that the file is now bigger than before and I'm not sure that the quality is better (as the image was already compressed). Now just doing

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fileoutputstream);
```

file size before: **1.5mb** - file size after **0.3 mb**

so surely with a quality of 80 I will have a lesser quality image than before. **So what quality does android use by default when a user takes a picture and saves it to the gallery**? How do I save the image with the same quality as before, without losing anything?

For an app like instagram/500px what is an acceptable image quality we can set before sending picture to the server? 50? 75? 80? 100?

Answer (score 0):

Every saving in JPEG is cost to you some quality loss. Even if you use "100% quality", some lossy compression will occur.

> How to save the image with the same quality as before, without loosing
>   anything ?

You can't save jpeg without quality loss. Only very specialized software can do some tricks without recompression, with very limited features like rotation by 90 degree.

> so surelly with a quality of 80 i will have a less quality than before
>
> So what quality does android use by default

JPEG standard not defines quality in percents at all. If you use "80%" in one program, it can be same as "50%" or "90%" in other. This is just numbers for some encoder.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG and PNG are both compress mode. So, it can not make sure the 100% quality.

For JPEG, in my case, i often use 90% for high quality, use 70% for low quality. In opencv, for `CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY`, default value is 90% quality.

Hope this is helpful.